# application.html.erb not letting the app to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

while creating a route to home#index from the route.rb file, it runs application.html.erb from the layout folder in view. Due to this the other routes are also not working. When i delete the application.html.erb file then the app runs smoothly. I believe that this applicaiton.html.erb is very important for us so i think its better not to delete. Is there any ways to run the app smoothly without deleting the file.

i tried writing

render :layout => false but i have to write in every action to not bring out the error message. I want to display some notice in my app but application.html.erb is not letting me..

Please help Thank you

Comment: What is the error message you are having?

Comment: @Ahmed sometimes routing error, and some other times syntax error as well

Comment: _some routing error_ doesn't say anything. [edit] the question with relevant error messages and the code that is giving you errors.

Comment: the errors shown in particular is: ExecJS::ProgramError in Home#index, Showing c:/Sites/just/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:, , TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method, this line is giving error they say:  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

Answer (score 1):

No need to write `render :layout => false` on every action, you can set layout false for all actions of controler by refer this example.

```
BlogsController < ApplicationController
  layout false
```

This will stop layout for all actions of Blogs controller.